Trim extra spaces from the beginning and end of a column
I am trying to trim any extra spaces from the beginning and end of a column called ID.
I have a global variable for this ID column and a macro to find where it is as the ID column's position can change with each submission.
My issue stems from the trim function. I want to trim the ID column using the variable I have defined as IDColumn, for all entries into the column which vary with each submission.
Attached is my declared variables and code I found here.
How do I set up the array using Range?
I get

application-defines or object defined error

I understand that I am not using range correctly. I have read that it wants string data, but I have also seen the range defined using cells().
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text
Global currentsheet, sheetcount, missbreak, criterror As Integer
Public duptest      As Integer
Public i            As Long
Public deleted_ID   As String
Public rlastcell    As Range
Global lrow, rowcount, columnCount, rowcount2, columncount2 As Long
Global OriginalRowCount As Long
Global x            As Long
Global y, IDColumn      As Integer
Global ThisIsADuplicate, ThisIsAMultiple As Boolean
Global arr, arr2        As Variant

Sub RemoveLeadingAndTrailingSpaces()
Dim V As Variant
V = Range(Cells(2, IDColumn), Cells(rowcount, IDColumn))
For i = 1 To UBound(V, 1)
    If V(i, 1) <> "" Then
        V(i, 1) = Trim(V(i, 1))
    End If
Next i
        
End Sub

I have headers on row 1 to find what column IDColumn is equal to.

Trim(V(i, 1)) will fail if for example V(i, 1) is an error value.   Also worth noting that in VBA every variable needs a type, otherwise it's a Variant - your comma-separated Dim statements don't do what you expect.

In the procedure RemoveLeadingAndTrailingSpaces you should write the array V to the worksheet at the end:
Range(Cells(2, IDColumn), Cells(rowcount, IDColumn)).Value = V
because at the moment, after the procedure is completed, the result of the action will be unavailable.

Here's an example of how to trim off the leading and trailing spaces including any excessive (more than one consecutive) spaces in between: Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet: Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("A2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)): rg.Value = Application.Trim(rg.Value). Using global variables is usually avoided. Not specifying the workbook and worksheet may lead to modifications in the wrong place.

@ Tim Williams, thank you for the heads up on the comma separated variables. I was not aware that they were being saved as a variant. I should have known with the watches I added but I guess I was just not paying attention to that.

For anyone who may look at this, I reused my own code from higher up and modified it a bit. May not be the best solution but I found that it does what I wanted it to do
    Sub RemoveLeadingAndTrailingSpaces()
Dim sh          As Worksheet
Dim sheetArr    As Variant
Dim test1, test2, test3 As String
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)
sheetArr = sh.UsedRange
For i = 2 To rowcount
    If Left(sheetArr(i, IDColumn), 1) = " " Then
            Cells(i, IDColumn) = Trim(Cells(i, IDColumn))
    End If
    If Right(sheetArr(i, IDColumn), 1) = " " Then
          Cells(i, IDColumn) = Trim(Cells(i, IDColumn))
    End If
    Next i
End Sub


In my previous comment, I meant that you don't need a loop. Applied to this code, you can simplify by using With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).UsedRange.Columns(IDColumn): .Value = Application.Trim(.Value): End With. Sure, it's a bit inaccurate because it includes the headers but it's more efficient and requires less typing.

@vbasics2008 I didn't specify this in the prompt as my main issue, and one I admittedly still have is a fundamental misunderstanding of how to define ranges, however I do think ill need to loop as I need the function to flag to the user where this issue has occurred. My overall macro is comparing two worksheets and flagging where any changes have been made. I needed the program to identify spacing issues, flag it for the user, fix the issue and then continue the comparison. I appreciate the code though. I'm sure ill be able to use the usedrange and application functions in the future now.
